# How to parse all json objects contained in a string?

Tags: json, string, matlab, parsing

I have a string that contains json objects (1x878683 char). When I parse them, I got a 1x1 struct that contains the first json object. The rest of json objects are skiped. I parse them using this matlab class [JSON.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42236-parse-json-text/content/example/html/usage.html) using JSON.parse method.
I want all json objects to be parsed and I want each json object to be an element of a cell array. How to do so?

This how my json string looks like:

```
  " {"Surname":" bla bla bla", "OtherNames":"pla pla pla", "Affiliation":"bla bla bla"} 
{"Surname":" bla bla bla", "OtherNames":"pla pla pla", "Affiliation":"bla bla bla"}
{"Surname":" bla bla bla", "OtherNames":"pla pla pla", "Affiliation":"bla bla bla"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON data sets should always have a root object. You have defined three separate objects. You'll want these to be contained in a root object, in an array. Like this:

```
{
    "persons": [{
        "Surname": " bla bla bla",
        "OtherNames": "pla pla pla",
        "Affiliation": "bla bla bla"
    }, {
        "Surname": " bla bla bla",
        "OtherNames": "pla pla pla",
        "Affiliation": "bla bla bla"
    }, {
        "Surname": " bla bla bla",
        "OtherNames": "pla pla pla",
        "Affiliation": "bla bla bla"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I've edited my json string as you've suggested. When I run the code I got this error `Error using JSON/getObject (line 99)
JSON parser requires commas between object elements` although that there are commas between them

Comment: the code that gives this error: `if strcmp(value,',')
                    value = this.getValue;
                elseif strcmp(value,']')
                    continue
                else
                    error('JSON parser requires commas between array elements');
                end
            end` . I tried to print value. Its value is NaN